# Gas grill flare up made flame covers look rusty

Tags: grilling, propane-grill

I had a fairly intense flare up on my KitchenAid gas grill (too much canola oil) that lasted about 30 seconds. The inside of the grill is covered in soot (expected) but the flame covers (triangle shaped pieces above the flame) are now copper colored and look rusty. I got most of that off with cleaning, but it seems weird for a big flare up to have caused it.

Anyone else ever have that happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! "Has this ever happened to anyone else?" isn't really a question we can answer because there's [no problem to be solved](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). What do you actually want to know? How to prevent it? How to clean up after it?

Comment: Thanks. Just curious if this flare up could cause rust? Or if copper coloring is a normal part of a grill aging and this isn't rust. I'm new to the world of grilling, so pardon the ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely rust. The covers over top of the burners will eventually experience that sort of decay. They have a constant barrage of high heat applied to them, which speeds oxidation of the metal. You will experience this effect with the burners as well.

Comment: Too right. Flame covers are the first part to go in a grill. High Heat speeds oxidation by a lot. When you strip cast iron lots in an oven cleaning cycle, they start out metal grey and then turn orange as they cool after opening up the oven.

Answer (score 1):

It might be rust, but if it was rather smooth and more orange-ish, it might've been that you ended up seasoning the metal.  (seasoning over shiny / polished metal tends to be orange until you have a few coats down when it'll get darker).

Of course, as you mentioned that you were able to clean it, it's more likely it's rust (as Sean Hart said), as seasoning can be rather difficult to get off without exposing it to more heat to completely bake it off.

...but I thought I'd mention this possibility in case anyone else has an oil spill and is wondering why aluminum or other non-iron object has gone orange-brown.